# Data in second column appears in the first one in html tabular forms

Tags: html, forms, html-table, opentext, livelink

I am creating a form for content server in html. Everything seems to be working fine functionally. However the alignment of some elements is creating problems. There are some elements which should appear in the second column of the table. Instead, they are appearing in the first one. For example, if we click on the radio button 'Group Based', the field which appears should be on the right hand side, in the second column. But it appears in the first column. Here is the HTML code. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/img/style/screen.css?v=1042.1045">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<title>New Access Request Form</title>

<style>
    .browseRow1 { background-color: #FFFFFF;  } 
    .browseRow2 { background-color: #FFFFFF;  } 
    h2 {
        margin-top: 20px;
        text-align:center;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }
    td {
        padding:5px;
    }
    .firstColumn {
        width: 300px;
    }
    table {
        padding-left: 200px;
        align-content:center;
        width:1000px;
        border:1px, solid, black;
    }
</style>

<SCRIPT SRC="/img/core/ajax_dhtml_util.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC="/img/webform/formssupport.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT>
    function chooseUser_1_1_2_1() {
        var     url;
        var     w;

        url =       '/OTCS/cs.exe?func=user.SelectUserDlg&formname=myForm&fieldprefix=_1_1_2_1&title=Select%20User&DisplayUserName&NoGroups=FALSE';

        url = url + '&NoGroupsSelectable=TRUE'
        w = window.open(url,"","height=340,width=680,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=yes,status=yes");

        if ( w.focus ) {
            w.focus();
        }
    }

    function KeepFieldSet_1_1_2_1( nameField, savedValue ) {
        if ( nameField.value != '' ) {
            alert( "You can't enter text in by hand. Use the link to the right." );
            nameField.value = savedValue;
        }
        else if ( markDirty != null ) {
            markDirty();
        }

        if ( nameField.value == savedValue.value ) {
            savedValue.value = nameField.value;
        }
    }

    function chooseUser_1_1_3_1() {
        var     url;
        var     w;
        url =   '/OTCS/cs.exe?func=user.SelectUserDlg&formname=myForm&fieldprefix=_1_1_3_1&title=Select%20User&DisplayUserName&NoGroups=FALSE';
        url = url + '&NoGroupsSelectable=TRUE'
        w = window.open(url,"","height=340,width=680,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=yes,status=yes");
        if ( w.focus ) {
            w.focus();
        }
    }

    function KeepFieldSet_1_1_3_1( nameField, savedValue ) {
        if ( nameField.value != '' ) {
            alert( "You can't enter text in by hand. Use the link to the right." );
            nameField.value = savedValue;
        }
        else if ( markDirty != null ) {
            markDirty();
        }

        if ( nameField.value == savedValue.value ) {
            savedValue.value = nameField.value;
        }
    }

    function showInstructions() {
        document.getElementById("instructions").style.display = "block";
    }
    function hideInstructions() {
        document.getElementById("instructions").style.display = "none";
    }
    function showGroup(){
        document.getElementById("ifGroup").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifGroup1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifUser").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifUser1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifCS").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifCS1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display="none";    
    }
    function showUser() {
        document.getElementById("ifGroup").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifGroup1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifUser").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifUser1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifCS").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifCS").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display="none";
    }
    function showCS() {
        document.getElementById("ifGroup").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifGroup1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifUser").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifUser1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifCS").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifCS1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display="none";
    }
    function showParent() {
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display="none";    
    }
    function showObj() {
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display="none";
    }
    function showCSItem() {
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display="block";    
        document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display="block";   
    }
    function doBrowseLivelink(formname,fieldprefix) {
        var w;

        w= window.open("/OTCS/cs.exe?func=ll&objType=150&objAction=targetBrowse&headerLabel=Browse%20to%20a%20Location&selectLabel=Select%20%3E&selectScreen%3D%7B0%2C130%2C130%2C133%2C134%2C136%2C138%2C139%2C141%2C142%2C148%2C149%2C154%2C180%2C201%2C202%2C205%2C206%2C208%2C210%2C211%2C212%2C233%2C236%2C268%2C269%2C270%2C275%2C276%2C290%2C327%2C336%2C370%2C398%2C403%2C480%2C481%2C482%2C483%2C484%2C530%2C526%2C527%2C528%2C529%2C530%2C530%2C541%2C542%2C557%2C731%2C730%2C751%2C753%2C795%2C796%2C870%2C899%2C900%2C901%2C905%2C908%2C919%2C1280%2C1281%2C2504%2C32657%2C298%2C215%2C143%2C203%2C150%7D&formname=" + formname + "&fieldprefix=" + fieldprefix + "" ,"SelectWidget","width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no");

        if(w.focus) {
            w.focus();
        }
    }
    function doBrowseLivelink1(formname,fieldprefix) {
        var win;

        win = window.open("/OTCS/cs.exe?func=ll&objType=150&objAction=targetBrowse&headerLabel=Browse%20to%20a%20Location&selectLabel=Select%20%3E&formname=" + formname + "&fieldprefix=" + fieldprefix + "" ,"SelectWidget","width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no");

        if(win.focus) {
            win.focus();
        }
    }

</SCRIPT>

</head>

<body>
    <h2>New Access Reqeust Form</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="firstColumn">
                <a onclick="showInstructions()" href="javascript:void(0);">Show Instructions</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="instructions" style="display: none;">
                    <ol>
                    <li>Select an option from <i>Group Based, User Based</i> and <i>Content Server(CS) Item Based</i>.</li>
                    <li>If you select <i>Group Based</i>, you will need to select one of the available CS groups and the permissions will be mapped to your account according to that group.</li>
                    <li>If you select <i>User Based</i>, you will need to select an existing user who already has the same permissions which you intend to request.</li> 
                    <li>If you select <i>CS Item Based,</i> you need to further select an option out of <i>Parent Item, Object ID/Node ID, CS Item</i>.</li>
                    <li>If you select <i>Parent Item</i>, you can browse the content server to find the parent folder/container of the item you need access to. You can specify in the comments section, the name of the specific item you need access to.</li>
                    <li>If you select <i>Object ID/Node ID</i>, you will have to specify the Object ID or Node ID of the item you need access to.</li>
                    <li>If you select <i>CS Item</i>, you can browse the content server to directly select the item to which you need access.</li>
                    <li>Then you need to select the level of access you require out of <i>Read, Write, Add</i> and <i>Full</i>.</li>
                    <li>Hit <i>Submit</i> when done.</li>
                    </ol>
                    <a onclick="hideInstructions()" href="javascript:void(0);">Hide Instructions</a>
                 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <FORM NAME="myForm" ACTION="/OTCS/cs.exe" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" METHOD="POST">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="func" VALUE="form.dispatch">
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="LL_FUNC_VALUES" VALUE="A&lt;1,?,'func'='Form.SaveForm','LL_FormViewID'=43767,'LL_ReadOnly'=false,'LL_TemplateID'=43545,'LL_TemplateVersion'=1,'nextUrl'='/OTCS/cs.exe?func=ll&amp;objId=43435&amp;objAction=browse','nodeID'=43986&gt;">
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="LL_AttrFieldName" VALUE="">
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="LL_AttrFieldIndex" VALUE="">
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="LL_WFATTURL" VALUE="">

        <tr>
            <td class="firstColumn">
                Permission Request Type
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="radioGroup" type="radio" name="permissiontype" onclick="javascript: showGroup();">Group Based
                <input id="radioUser" type="radio" name="permissiontype" onclick="javascript: showUser();">User Based
                <input id="radioCS" type="radio" name="permissiontype" onclick="javascript: showCS();">Content Server Item Based Based
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="firstColumn" id ="ifGroup" style="display: none">
                Select Group
            </td>
            <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_1_1_2_1_ID" VALUE="">
            <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_1_1_2_1_SavedName" VALUE="">
            <td id ="ifGroup1" style="display: none">
                <LABEL FOR="_1_1_2_1_Name"></LABEL>
                <INPUT CLASS="valueEditable" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="_1_1_2_1_Name" ID="_1_1_2_1_Name" VALUE="" ALT=  "Select User" SIZE="23" ONCHANGE="KeepFieldSet_1_1_2_1( this, this.form._1_1_2_1_SavedName.value )">
                <A HREF="javascript:chooseUser_1_1_2_1()"><IMG SRC="/img/guy_select.gif" ALT="Select User" BORDER="0"></A>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="firstColumn" id ="ifUser" style="display: none">
                Select User
            </td>
            <td id ="ifUser1" style="display: none">
                <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_1_1_3_1_ID" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_1_1_3_1_SavedName" VALUE="">

                <LABEL FOR="_1_1_3_1_Name"></LABEL>
                <INPUT CLASS="valueEditable" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="_1_1_3_1_Name" ID="_1_1_3_1_Name" VALUE="" ALT="Select User" SIZE="23" ONCHANGE="KeepFieldSet_1_1_3_1( this, this.form._1_1_3_1_SavedName.value )">
                <A HREF="javascript:chooseUser_1_1_3_1()"><IMG SRC="/img/guy_select.gif" ALT="Select User" BORDER="0"></A>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ifCS" style="display: none;">
            <td class="firstColumn">
                Select an option
            </td>
            <td id="ifCS1" style="display: none;">
                <input id="radioParent" type="radio" name="permissiontype1" onclick="javascript: showParent();">Parent Item
                <input id="radioObj" type="radio" name="permissiontype1" onclick="javascript: showObj();">Object ID/Node ID
                <input id="radioItem" type="radio" name="permissiontype1" onclick="javascript: showCSItem();">Content Server(CS) Item
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id ="ifParentItem" style="display: none">
                URL to Parent Item
            </td>
            <td id ="ifParentItem1" style="display: none">
                <DIV STYLE="display: none">
                    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value1_ID" NAME="BrowseLivelink_value1_ID" VALUE="">
                    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value1_PathSaved" NAME="BrowseLivelink_value1_PathSaved" VALUE="">
                </DIV>

                <INPUT title="Click the Browse Content Server button" READONLY CLASS="valueEditable" type="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value1_Path" name="BrowseLivelink_value1_Path" value="" size="40" ONCHANGE="KeepFieldSet(this, this.form.BrowseLivelink_value1_PathSaved, this.form.BrowseLivelink_value1_ID" > 
                <input class="button" type="BUTTON" name="BrowseLivelink_Button" title="Browse Content Server... Opens a new window." value="Browse Content Server..." onclick="javascript:doBrowseLivelink('myForm','BrowseLivelink_value1')">
                &nbsp;
                <br> <br><TEXTAREA CLASS="valueEditable multiline" ID="_1_1_8_1" NAME="_1_1_8_1" TITLE="Comments" WRAP="soft" ROWS="3" COLS="32" ONFOCUS="" ONCHANGE="markDirty();" placeholder="Comments"></TEXTAREA>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="ifObj" style="display: none;">
                Object ID of the Item
            </td>
            <td id="ifObj1" style="display: none;">
                <INPUT CLASS="valueEditable" TYPE="text" NAME="_1_1_5_1" TITLE="Object ID of the Item" ID="_1_1_5_1" VALUE="" SIZE="32" MAXLENGTH="32" ONCHANGE="markDirty();">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="ifItem" style="display: none;">
                URL to the Item
            </td>
            <td id="ifItem1" style="display: none;">
                <DIV STYLE="display: none">
                    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value2_ID" NAME="BrowseLivelink_value2_ID" VALUE="">
                    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value2_PathSaved" NAME="BrowseLivelink_value2_PathSaved" VALUE="">
                </DIV>
                <INPUT title="Click the Browse Content Server button" READONLY CLASS="valueEditable" type="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value2_Path" name="BrowseLivelink_value2_Path" value="" size="40" ONCHANGE="KeepFieldSet(this, this.form.BrowseLivelink_value2_PathSaved, this.form.BrowseLivelink_value2_ID" > 
                <input class="button" type="BUTTON" name="BrowseLivelink_Button" title="Browse Content Server... Opens a new window." value="Browse Content Server..." onclick="javascript:doBrowseLivelink1('myForm','BrowseLivelink_value2')">
&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Access Level Required <IMG SRC="/img/required.gif" ALT="Required" TITLE="Required" BORDER="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <SELECT CLASS="selectMenu" ID="_1_1_7_1" NAME="_1_1_7_1" ONCHANGE="markDirty();">
                    <OPTION VALUE="" >&lt;None&gt;</OPTION>

                    <OPTION VALUE="Read" >Read</OPTION>
                    <OPTION VALUE="Modify" >Modify</OPTION>
                    <OPTION VALUE="Add" >Add</OPTION>
                    <OPTION VALUE="Full" >Full</OPTION>
                </SELECT>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <INPUT CLASS="applyButton" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Submit" NAME="IgnoreMe" ONCLICK="doFormSubmit( document.myForm );">
                <INPUT CLASS="resetButton" TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Reset">
            </td>
        </tr>
      </FORM>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with table, you should use `display:table-cell` instead of `display:block` for `<TD>`

```js
function chooseUser_1_1_2_1() {
  var url;
  var w;

  url = '/OTCS/cs.exe?func=user.SelectUserDlg&formname=myForm&fieldprefix=_1_1_2_1&title=Select%20User&DisplayUserName&NoGroups=FALSE';

  url = url + '&NoGroupsSelectable=TRUE'
  w = window.open(url, "", "height=340,width=680,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=yes,status=yes");

  if (w.focus) {
    w.focus();
  }
}

function KeepFieldSet_1_1_2_1(nameField, savedValue) {
  if (nameField.value != '') {
    alert("You can't enter text in by hand. Use the link to the right.");
    nameField.value = savedValue;
  } else if (markDirty != null) {
    markDirty();
  }

  if (nameField.value == savedValue.value) {
    savedValue.value = nameField.value;
  }
}

function chooseUser_1_1_3_1() {
  var url;
  var w;
  url = '/OTCS/cs.exe?func=user.SelectUserDlg&formname=myForm&fieldprefix=_1_1_3_1&title=Select%20User&DisplayUserName&NoGroups=FALSE';
  url = url + '&NoGroupsSelectable=TRUE'
  w = window.open(url, "", "height=340,width=680,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=yes,status=yes");
  if (w.focus) {
    w.focus();
  }
}

function KeepFieldSet_1_1_3_1(nameField, savedValue) {
  if (nameField.value != '') {
    alert("You can't enter text in by hand. Use the link to the right.");
    nameField.value = savedValue;
  } else if (markDirty != null) {
    markDirty();
  }

  if (nameField.value == savedValue.value) {
    savedValue.value = nameField.value;
  }
}

function showInstructions() {
  document.getElementById("instructions").style.display = "block";
}

function hideInstructions() {
  document.getElementById("instructions").style.display = "none";
}

function showGroup() {
  document.getElementById("ifGroup").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifGroup1").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifUser").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifUser1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifCS").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifCS1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display = "none";
}

function showUser() {
  document.getElementById("ifGroup").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifGroup1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifUser").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifUser1").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifCS").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifCS").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display = "none";
}

function showCS() {
  document.getElementById("ifGroup").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifGroup1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifUser").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifUser1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifCS").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifCS1").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display = "none";
}

function showParent() {
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display = "none";
}

function showObj() {
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display = "none";
}

function showCSItem() {
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifParentItem1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifObj1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ifItem").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("ifItem1").style.display = "table-cell";
}

function doBrowseLivelink(formname, fieldprefix) {
  var w;

  w = window.open("/OTCS/cs.exe?func=ll&objType=150&objAction=targetBrowse&headerLabel=Browse%20to%20a%20Location&selectLabel=Select%20%3E&selectScreen%3D%7B0%2C130%2C130%2C133%2C134%2C136%2C138%2C139%2C141%2C142%2C148%2C149%2C154%2C180%2C201%2C202%2C205%2C206%2C208%2C210%2C211%2C212%2C233%2C236%2C268%2C269%2C270%2C275%2C276%2C290%2C327%2C336%2C370%2C398%2C403%2C480%2C481%2C482%2C483%2C484%2C530%2C526%2C527%2C528%2C529%2C530%2C530%2C541%2C542%2C557%2C731%2C730%2C751%2C753%2C795%2C796%2C870%2C899%2C900%2C901%2C905%2C908%2C919%2C1280%2C1281%2C2504%2C32657%2C298%2C215%2C143%2C203%2C150%7D&formname=" + formname + "&fieldprefix=" + fieldprefix + "", "SelectWidget", "width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no");

  if (w.focus) {
    w.focus();
  }
}

function doBrowseLivelink1(formname, fieldprefix) {
  var win;

  win = window.open("/OTCS/cs.exe?func=ll&objType=150&objAction=targetBrowse&headerLabel=Browse%20to%20a%20Location&selectLabel=Select%20%3E&formname=" + formname + "&fieldprefix=" + fieldprefix + "", "SelectWidget", "width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no");

  if (win.focus) {
    win.focus();
  }
}
```

```css
.browseRow1 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.browseRow2 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.firstColumn {
  width: 300px;
}
table {
  padding-left: 200px;
  align-content: center;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px, solid, black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/img/style/screen.css?v=1042.1045">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>New Access Request Form</title>

  <SCRIPT SRC="/img/core/ajax_dhtml_util.js"></SCRIPT>
  <SCRIPT SRC="/img/webform/formssupport.js"></SCRIPT>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>New Access Reqeust Form</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="firstColumn">
        <a onclick="showInstructions()" href="javascript:void(0);">Show Instructions</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="instructions" style="display: none;">
          <ol>
            <li>Select an option from <i>Group Based, User Based</i> and <i>Content Server(CS) Item Based</i>.</li>
            <li>If you select <i>Group Based</i>, you will need to select one of the available CS groups and the permissions will be mapped to your account according to that group.</li>
            <li>If you select <i>User Based</i>, you will need to select an existing user who already has the same permissions which you intend to request.</li>
            <li>If you select <i>CS Item Based,</i> you need to further select an option out of <i>Parent Item, Object ID/Node ID, CS Item</i>.</li>
            <li>If you select <i>Parent Item</i>, you can browse the content server to find the parent folder/container of the item you need access to. You can specify in the comments section, the name of the specific item you need access to.</li>
            <li>If you select <i>Object ID/Node ID</i>, you will have to specify the Object ID or Node ID of the item you need access to.</li>
            <li>If you select <i>CS Item</i>, you can browse the content server to directly select the item to which you need access.</li>
            <li>Then you need to select the level of access you require out of <i>Read, Write, Add</i> and <i>Full</i>.</li>
            <li>Hit <i>Submit</i> when done.</li>
          </ol>
          <a onclick="hideInstructions()" href="javascript:void(0);">Hide Instructions</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <FORM NAME="myForm" ACTION="/OTCS/cs.exe" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" METHOD="POST">

      <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="func" VALUE="form.dispatch">
      <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="LL_FUNC_VALUES" VALUE="A&lt;1,?,'func'='Form.SaveForm','LL_FormViewID'=43767,'LL_ReadOnly'=false,'LL_TemplateID'=43545,'LL_TemplateVersion'=1,'nextUrl'='/OTCS/cs.exe?func=ll&amp;objId=43435&amp;objAction=browse','nodeID'=43986&gt;">
      <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="LL_AttrFieldName" VALUE="">
      <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="LL_AttrFieldIndex" VALUE="">
      <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="LL_WFATTURL" VALUE="">

      <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn">
          Permission Request Type
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="radioGroup" type="radio" name="permissiontype" onclick="javascript: showGroup();">Group Based
          <input id="radioUser" type="radio" name="permissiontype" onclick="javascript: showUser();">User Based
          <input id="radioCS" type="radio" name="permissiontype" onclick="javascript: showCS();">Content Server Item Based Based
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn" id="ifGroup" style="display: none">
          Select Group
        </td>
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_1_1_2_1_ID" VALUE="">
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_1_1_2_1_SavedName" VALUE="">
        <td id="ifGroup1" style="display: none">
          <LABEL FOR="_1_1_2_1_Name"></LABEL>
          <INPUT CLASS="valueEditable" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="_1_1_2_1_Name" ID="_1_1_2_1_Name" VALUE="" ALT="Select User" SIZE="23" ONCHANGE="KeepFieldSet_1_1_2_1( this, this.form._1_1_2_1_SavedName.value )">
          <A HREF="javascript:chooseUser_1_1_2_1()">
            <IMG SRC="/img/guy_select.gif" ALT="Select User" BORDER="0">
          </A>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn" id="ifUser" style="display: none">
          Select User
        </td>
        <td id="ifUser1" style="display: none">
          <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_1_1_3_1_ID" VALUE="">
          <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_1_1_3_1_SavedName" VALUE="">

          <LABEL FOR="_1_1_3_1_Name"></LABEL>
          <INPUT CLASS="valueEditable" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="_1_1_3_1_Name" ID="_1_1_3_1_Name" VALUE="" ALT="Select User" SIZE="23" ONCHANGE="KeepFieldSet_1_1_3_1( this, this.form._1_1_3_1_SavedName.value )">
          <A HREF="javascript:chooseUser_1_1_3_1()">
            <IMG SRC="/img/guy_select.gif" ALT="Select User" BORDER="0">
          </A>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="ifCS" style="display: none;">
        <td class="firstColumn">
          Select an option
        </td>
        <td id="ifCS1" style="display: none;">
          <input id="radioParent" type="radio" name="permissiontype1" onclick="javascript: showParent();">Parent Item
          <input id="radioObj" type="radio" name="permissiontype1" onclick="javascript: showObj();">Object ID/Node ID
          <input id="radioItem" type="radio" name="permissiontype1" onclick="javascript: showCSItem();">Content Server(CS) Item
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="ifParentItem" style="display: none">
          URL to Parent Item
        </td>
        <td id="ifParentItem1" style="display: none">
          <DIV STYLE="display: none">
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value1_ID" NAME="BrowseLivelink_value1_ID" VALUE="">
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value1_PathSaved" NAME="BrowseLivelink_value1_PathSaved" VALUE="">
          </DIV>

          <INPUT title="Click the Browse Content Server button" READONLY CLASS="valueEditable" type="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value1_Path" name="BrowseLivelink_value1_Path" value="" size="40" ONCHANGE="KeepFieldSet(this, this.form.BrowseLivelink_value1_PathSaved, this.form.BrowseLivelink_value1_ID">
          <input class="button" type="BUTTON" name="BrowseLivelink_Button" title="Browse Content Server... Opens a new window." value="Browse Content Server..." onclick="javascript:doBrowseLivelink('myForm','BrowseLivelink_value1')">&nbsp;
          <br>
          <br>
          <TEXTAREA CLASS="valueEditable multiline" ID="_1_1_8_1" NAME="_1_1_8_1" TITLE="Comments" WRAP="soft" ROWS="3" COLS="32" ONFOCUS="" ONCHANGE="markDirty();" placeholder="Comments"></TEXTAREA>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="ifObj" style="display: none;">
          Object ID of the Item
        </td>
        <td id="ifObj1" style="display: none;">
          <INPUT CLASS="valueEditable" TYPE="text" NAME="_1_1_5_1" TITLE="Object ID of the Item" ID="_1_1_5_1" VALUE="" SIZE="32" MAXLENGTH="32" ONCHANGE="markDirty();">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="ifItem" style="display: none;">
          URL to the Item
        </td>
        <td id="ifItem1" style="display: none;">
          <DIV STYLE="display: none">
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value2_ID" NAME="BrowseLivelink_value2_ID" VALUE="">
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value2_PathSaved" NAME="BrowseLivelink_value2_PathSaved" VALUE="">
          </DIV>
          <INPUT title="Click the Browse Content Server button" READONLY CLASS="valueEditable" type="TEXT" ID="BrowseLivelink_value2_Path" name="BrowseLivelink_value2_Path" value="" size="40" ONCHANGE="KeepFieldSet(this, this.form.BrowseLivelink_value2_PathSaved, this.form.BrowseLivelink_value2_ID">
          <input class="button" type="BUTTON" name="BrowseLivelink_Button" title="Browse Content Server... Opens a new window." value="Browse Content Server..." onclick="javascript:doBrowseLivelink1('myForm','BrowseLivelink_value2')">&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Access Level Required
          <IMG SRC="/img/required.gif" ALT="Required" TITLE="Required" BORDER="0">
        </td>
        <td>
          <SELECT CLASS="selectMenu" ID="_1_1_7_1" NAME="_1_1_7_1" ONCHANGE="markDirty();">
            <OPTION VALUE="">&lt;None&gt;</OPTION>

            <OPTION VALUE="Read">Read</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Modify">Modify</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Add">Add</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Full">Full</OPTION>
          </SELECT>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <INPUT CLASS="applyButton" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Submit" NAME="IgnoreMe" ONCLICK="doFormSubmit( document.myForm );">
          <INPUT CLASS="resetButton" TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Reset">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </FORM>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```